# In which file dropdown editor values are stored in SuiteCRM

Tags: php, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I'm using `suitecrm 7.7` version.

Before that I used `suitecrm 7.3.` I got some problems in suitecrm 7.3 so moved to suitecrm 7.7 but backend i'm using same old database only.

I've created some of the dropdowns in `suitecrm 7.3 dropdown editor`. I want to import those dropdown lists to suitecrm 7.7

Please tell me in which file `dropdown editor` values are stored.

Answer (score 2):

Usually they go into their extensions...

Locations can be depends upon their level either they are module level or application level.

1) a module level extension will be there .. custom/Extension/modules/module_name/Ext/Language

2) An application level extension will be there...
custom/Extension/application/Ext/Language/

3) There might be changes of this location as well...
custom/include/Language/

keep in mind it language file depends upon your preferred language ie in case of US English, it will be something suffix .en_us.php

Answer (score 1):

Above answer is Windows-specific, involves using Notepad++ to search for strings in directory.

The file that these values are stored in is usually: 
[SuiteCRM DocRoot]/include/language/en_us.lang.php

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.

Please refer below link:

https://suitecrm.com/forum/developer-help/11271-in-which-file-dropdown-editor-values-are-stored-in-suitecrm#38384